# dat.GUI controls not properly rendered in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, dat.gui

I have used dat.GUI in my project. It looks like this on my localhost - [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Xqv.png)

However when I embed it in my Ionic project, it looks like this - [Under Ionic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WEra.png)
The sliders are not showing up and manually entering values does not work.
The buttons are working but they have this weird white patch in between.

I checked for any overriding css but could not find any.
What is going wrong?

Comment: Need some sample code to help you